# Is it possible to use the DASH7 protocol in an arduino?

Tags: rf

I've been reading about the protocol DASH7 but can't find much documentation about it. There seems to be a protocol stack called OpenTag writen in C and I want to know if there is something familiar written in arduino code and why can't I find a lot about this tecnology.

Comment: The google-fu is weak with this one. http://www.dash7-alliance.org/?page_id=34  http://www.wizzilab.com/solutions/wizzikit/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DASH7

Comment: @JRE a development kit and a Wikipedia article... meh, It's not "Taylor Swift" popular.

Comment: You ask if Dash7 can be used with an Arduino and mumble about OpenTag.  I point you at developer kits that mention OpenTag and OSS as libraries and you go Meh.  Did you already know about them?  If you did, what isn't clear about how it works?

Comment: @JRE The second part of the question was to know why the technology wasn't popular. It had passed years and I can't see any new developments about it. I though you where trying to contradict it by showing those links, my bad.

Comment: I hadn't heard of DASH7 before, but I checked the website and I'm not enthusiastic. To get the free(!) spec the site plays games with you, demanding to add it to a shopping cart, asking for a lot of personal information, etc. They're a nuisance. If that's the level of service for people whom you have to win over for your product, what level of service can you expect later on, after you've been won over already?